Regarding Benders Decomposition for Master Problem with Binary Variables and Sub-problem with Integers (Not Continuous Variables)
I have a question on Benders Decomposition (BD). I have a MILP model which can be decomposed into a master problem (MP) comprising only binary variables and a subproblem (SP) though containing only integer variables, and can be solved as a LP.
In addition, the subproblem contains Big M constraints, which I understand will reappear within the optimality cuts that are to be used in the Master Problem.
Will the optimality cut generated be weak in which it does not enable the existing solution to be cut off while leaving better solutions? This is because though the upper bound improves, the LB remains stagnant.
I understand that classical Benders mandate that the subproblem be LP, and is unable to handle discrete subproblems which would require the use of other more involved machinery such as Logic Based and Combinatorial variants, of which I try not to be too intrepid for obvious reasons.
Thus, I would like to ask if Classical Benders would suffice if the Big M values are capped at a optimal value, given the structure of my problem.
If not, are there any workaround while ensuring eventual optimality?
